# Confused about setup type

Tags: installshield

I have my setup type dialog looking like this :

[image]

The top option is a custom one I added.

So in my next button push event, I have this :

[image]

So what I would now like to do is load up the custom setup dialog, but those features should be enabled / disabled depending on what was selected.

OR

If completer or first custom option is selected, I want to open a dialog conditionally.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Note the 'value' attribute of your new radio button (by default it should be '3')
2. Add the appropriate events with the condition _IsSetupTypeMin = "value"

Here is an example showing how to define the 'Next' button behavior to do the following:

- When selecting 'typical' it will select the proj_files feature and
  proceed to the ReadyToInstall dialog
- When selecting 'custom' it would
  go to the CustomSetup dialog
- When selecting the special option it
  will add feature2 and remove the proj_files feature, then proceed to
  the CustomSetup dialog.

[image]